# Trigger a maven install command from another maven install command

Tags: maven-2

Is there a way to trigger a maven install command from another maven install command?

In other words, I would like to be able to execute a maven install command on a maven project (in eclipse) and I want that this will automatically cause an install command on another maven project. 
Is that possible?

Answer (score 4):

The Maven way to "trigger" another build is to define a [multi-module build](http://www.sonatype.com/books/maven-book/reference/multimodule.html). A parent pom project can specify modules, that will all be built using the standard lifecycle. So running `mvn install` on the parent would mean that each module is built in turn.

The parent is defined with `pom` packagin, and would have a modules declaration like this:

```
<modules>
  <module>module-a</module>
  <module>module-b</module>
</modules>
```

Alternatively it is possible to attach additional artifacts to a build so they are deployed alongside the primary artifacts (assuming they've already been packaged, you can use the [build-helper-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/) to [attach](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/attach-artifact-mojo.html) an arbitrary file to your pom, so it will be deployed with the specified classifier. The following configuration will attach the specified file as `my-artifact-1.0-extra.jar`

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>attach-artifacts</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <artifacts>
            <artifact>
              <file>/path/to/extra/file.jar</file>
              <type>jar</type><!--or specify your required extension-->
              <classifier>extra</classifier>
            </artifact>
          </artifacts>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out, the maven way to launch a goal (lets say `mvn install`) on a set of modules is to organize them as a multi-module project and to launch the goal on the parent pom. Behind the scene, Maven will use a "Maven reactor" for this work. The reactor will calculate the build order by doing a topological sort of the nodes of the directed graph constructed by the dependency relation between modules. This graph is constructed by looking at `<modules>` and `<dependencies>` tags in poms.

But launching maven from a parent is not the only option and maven offers more possibilities to play with the reactor (e.g. making a project and its dependencies or those that depend on it):

- With maven 2.0.x you have to use the reactor plugin : http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-reactor-plugin/ (see [Reactor: My New Favourite Maven Plugin](http://brettporter.wordpress.com/2008/09/19/reactor-my-new-favourite-maven-plugin/) too)
- With maven 2.1+ you can use native command line options : http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/03/maven-210-released/ (see the new build mode options `-amd`, `-rf`, `-am`, `-pl`)

Check it out, it might help you to achieve your goal.