# building dependencies in a jar type maven project

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies

I have a maven project with package type jar which has some dependencies which will be packed in the resulting jar file when building the project. Some of those dependencies are my own projects which I'd like to automatically re-build when I build the current project. How can this be achieved? I currently only found the `<modules>` section which can only be used with package type pom, so this seems to be out of the question. Any ideas on this problem? Here a short example of the packages current pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>myproject2</name>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>mymainclass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15</version>
                <configuration>
                    <enableAssertions>false</enableAssertions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        [... some external dependencies ...]
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
            <artifactId>myproject1/artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

---

### UPDATE:

To elaborate on the development problem I try to solve:

Imagine you have both projects open in your IDE (I use netbeans). You are debugging myproject2 to track down some bug. You navigate by jumping through the code by klicking on Class names or by following the steps in the debugger.

This may often lead to changes in myproject1 without you even noticing it. In result the you would rebuild myproject2 (which you are debugging) without myproject1 being rebuild automatically. The error still happens and you may be clueless why this happens and search and search for another bug until you realize you didn't rebuild myproject1 before. You would then have to rebuild myproject1 afterwards myproject2 and then would have the correct behaviour (or the next bug). This happens quite often at work.

The same can happen with a separate multi-project POM which essentially is another project which will/can be forgotten when working on the code in the IDE.

Comment: You can find some useful information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502695/trigger-a-maven-install-command-from-another-maven-install-command

Answer (score 0):

You can create a multi-module project that includes the project in question and dependent projects as modules. The parent project will be of type "pom" but triggering a build on the parent project will result in a re-build of all modules.

```
    <groupId>group</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>dependency.1</module>
        <module>dependency.2</module>
        <module>your.project</module>       
    </modules>
```

Comment: If I correctly understand this: the project with your pom example would be used as a parent project to 'your.project' with my pom above? Wouldn't this be kind of a circular dependency?

Comment: This is not a parent / child relationship, but a multi-module project which brings together your project and dependencies.

Comment: Ok so I have my project with my current POM and additionally define the multi-project POM and instead of building my project I build the multi-project POM? This seems quite impractical to me. What I mainly try to achieve is an easier workflow while developing your.project and it would be way more convenient if this could be achieved with just invoking the build on your.project instead of a separate one.

Comment: I didn't find having a multi-module project to be a big overhead. I would be interested if there are any other approaches that are more convenient.

Comment: If you use the Eclipse M2E plugin for example, you can configure maven to resolve dependencies in the workspace. So any changes made locally to your project will be picked up automatically. I am not sure about NetBeans however

Comment: Netbeans does resolve the project automatically (thats why I can directly jump to code from other projects), it's coupling relies heavily on maven however. It doesn't invoke a mvn install on every change in code (which is good as this usually takes it's time), and it just invokes mvn install on the project thats supposed to be rebuild. No extra IDE magic which is good I think because this leads to the same results as calling mvn directly on the cmd line (elliminates error causes).

Comment: I will try the multi-project approach and see how it performs against building changed dependencies manually. More solutions are welcome however :)